# Dimension of finite type algebras over fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $S$ be a finite type $k$-algebra and $X=Spec(S)$ it's corresponding spectrum. Fothermore et $p \subset S$ be a prime ideal and $x \in X$ be the corresponding point.

I have a question about a step in the proof of Lemma 10.113.5 from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00OO:

If $Z$ is a irreducible component of $X$ and $W$ is an arbitrary open subset of $Z$ containing $x$, obviously we have $\dim (W) \leq \dim (Z)$.

The proof in another direction isn't clear to me. Indeed $W$ has always closed points but why then lemma 10.113.4 in this case imply already that there exist a chain of irreducible closed subsets of length equal to $dim(Z)$ in the open $W$.

Can anybody explain how this argument works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z$ is a closed subscheme of the affine scheme $X$, so it is $\operatorname{Spec} S/I$ for some ideal $I$. Since $Z$ is irreducible, $S/I$ is an integral domain; since $S$ is finite type over a field, $S/I$ is as well, and we may apply Lemma 10.113.4 to $S/I$. By the correspondence between prime ideals and irreducible closed subsets, we have found a chain as was requested.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. One step isn't clear: From 10.113.4 we get indeed a chain of primes $(p_0) \subset (p_1) ...  \subset (p_n) =m$ where $n=\dim Z$ and $x=x_m$. According to the correspondence this chain provides a chain of irred closed $x=Z_0 \subset Z_1 ... \subset Z_n$. By assumption $x \in W$, but the cruical point is why every $Z_i \subset W$?

Comment: Intersect with $W$. All resulting intersections will be irreducible subsets which are closed in the subspace topology, and proper inclusions will remain proper.